# console.log(Wrapper.debug()) not showing the react component

Tags: testing, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I am using enzyme with jest and trying to print out wrapper.debug but I am not getting output as shown in jest docs. what is wrong here? 
my test file:

```
import React  from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import App  from './../../components/App/App';



Enzyme.configure({ adapter : new EnzymeAdapter() });

it('should render without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />)


 console.log(wrapper.debug());

});
```

my console output is this :

```
 PASS  src/test/integration/App.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log src/test/integration/App.test.js:14
      <ContextConsumer>
        [function bound renderWrappedComponent]
      </ContextConsumer>


Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.8s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Answer (score 1):

The shallow rendering is useful to test a component as a unit so it won't dive and look for your component within `<ContextConsumer>`.

Some options:

- You could shallow directly the component within `<ContextConsumer>`.
- You could change shallow with mount which render the full DOM rendering (probably not your intent here).
- Use `.dive()` which shallow render the one non-DOM child of the current wrapper. [Doc](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

Comment: can you write the code as I am beginner to enzyme and whole testing in react